# ESXI/KVM with Windows 10 as daily driver

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtual-machine, esxi

Would it be okay or even beneficial to install ESXI or any similar hypervisor on my daily driver and run Windows 10 as a VM? I'm not really hoping for major benefits so this is more of an experiment/adventure, but I don't want to go in completely blind.
For example I would like to be able to have a linux OS installed alongside it that I can quickly switch to.
Are there any major issues I could run into?

Comment: Do you have the license to VCenter, View, and the other required hardware to run Windows on an ESXi host?  None of those mind you are free

Comment: @Ramhound Licenses aren't the issue here, since I'm still talking hypothetical, but if I decide to pull through I'll obviously get those.

Comment: How do you plan to access these VMs?

Comment: I don't know about any specifics yet, and I'm pretty new to virtualization but I just want to know if it's feasible in general.

Comment: Sounds like you should do more research.  If you don't know HOW you will access the VMs that are managed by ESXi we can't really tell you if your plan is feasible.

Comment: ESXI is a bare metal virtual app. I have seen this on servers, not on workstations. I have VMware Workstation on my Windows 10 "daily driver".  On that about 1 dozen virtual machines, main ones: Windows 7 (for support), Ubuntu and Kali.  They are really easy to run and with VMware V16, I can suspend the machine (which suspends the VMs) to take it somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not.

You never interact, console level, with the virtual machines on the physical host they are run on. You need a second computer to run the remote management or access tools to connect to the sessions of the VMs.

On a single computer you'd see the ESXi host UI, which is minimal and appropriate for a server not really intended to be looked at, ever. There would be no way to view the actual VMs from that computer.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Seems I need to learn a lot more about how virtual machines work haha.